# Python 2.7: serial.serialutil.SerialException: Port is already open. How to close this port?

Tags: python-2.7, serial-port, pyserial

I was trying to send integer to Arduino and so I wrote following code in Python 2.7 version:

```
import serial
import time

ser  = serial.Serial('COM8', 9600, timeout = 1)
# let it initialize
ser.open()
time.sleep(2)


ser.write(1)


while 1:
    bytess = ser.readline()
    print 'you sent : ' + bytess
```

Here, I forget to use `ser.close()` so now when I tried to run above code again it shows error :

```
File "D:/python/python to arduino.py", line 20, in <module>
    ser.open()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 41, in open
    raise SerialException("Port is already open.")
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Port is already open.
```

To avoid this error I unplug my Arduino cable and restart Python but it doesn't help. In Matlab for the same problem, if we close Matlab, problem is solved but the same thing is not happening with Python. I want to know how to close this open port now. Even after restart my laptop, same error is coming.

Thanks.

Comment: Just add `ser.close()` before `ser.open()`.

Answer (score 4):

In the [pySerial documentation about the `Serial` class](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial) :

> The port is immediately opened on object creation, when a *port* is given. It is not opened when *port* is `None` and a successive call to `open()` is required.

So when you do `ser  = serial.Serial('COM8', 9600, timeout = 1)`, you already open the port as you specified `'COM8'`, so you don't have to open it again.

Answer (score 1):

I find this problem too.
my serial is RS232 and just connect Grounding/RX/TX from my device to laptop.
I just ignore the open step and the directly write cmd to serial, but I get the collect feedback.
So, I guess we don't have to open serial before we handle it in some case